# How can we know whether an object is marked as garbage by GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Is there any tool to visualize the status of GC on a specific object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the object, it is trivially not collectable.

The JVMTI system (Java Virtual Machine Tool Interface) lets other processes link up to a JVM and get stats from it. It's what debuggers and profilers use; visualvm (ships with most JDKs) can do this, as can many commercial offerings. They give you some GC insights.

The JDK itself can do so as well, using `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` - [read this article](https://sematext.com/blog/java-garbage-collection-logs/) for more.

From within the same JVM, you can use the classes in `java.lang.ref` to make references to objects without impeding garbage collection. Trivially:

```
class Test {
  private final WeakReference<String> weakRef;

  public void test() {
    String y = new String("");
    weakRef = new WeakReference<>(y);
  }

  public boolean hasItBeenCollectedYet() {
    // weak refs don't impede collection; `.get()` returns null once
    // the object begins its collection process.
    return weakRef.get() == null;
  }
}
```

But, using that system to just gather up general stats? It's not great at it - the other two options are much nicer.

Comment: Note that `weakRef.get() == null` puts a strong object reference on the stack temporarily if the object has not been collected yet, which may prevent the collection of the object if a concurrent collector checks right at this moment (or sees some flag telling that the object has been accessed during the GC cycle). Starting with JDK 16, you can use `weakRef.refersTo(null)` to check this without receiving a strong reference. The alternative is to use a `ReferenceQueue` and check whether the `weakRef` has been enqueued.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there isn't a good way.

And there isn't **any** way to do it within a program that doesn't (in various ways) alter the behavior of the object that you trying to examine.

The "not good" ways are:

- By using `Reference` types.  The problem is that this alters the object's lifetime, and only tells you the object's status at the last point in time that the GC ran.
- By taking a heap dump and examining it with a heap dump analyzer.  The problem is that taking a heap dump is an expensive "stop the world" event, it uses a lot of disk space and it needs a lot of RAM to load and analyze the dump.

Finally, you *probably* won't learn much by doing this unless you are searching for a suspected memory leak.

Comment: Any good heap dump tool? I just want to do a little experiment on that.

Comment: Try visualvm to analyze heap dumps.